# Filtering on Nested Aggregation Binding

Tags: sapui5

I want to be able to apply a filter to a nested aggregation binding, but it doesn't seem to work.  Here is the XML:

```
<l:Grid id="test" defaultSpan="L6 M6 S6" content="{path : 'test>/', templateShareable:false}">
  <l:content>
    <VBox width="100%">
      <HBox height="100px" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Start">
        <VBox alignItems="Center" width="25%">
          <core:Icon src="{test>icon}" width="100%" />
          <Text text="{test>text}" width="100%"/>
        </VBox>
        <VBox id="test" height="80px" items="{path: 'test>data/', templateShareable:false}">
          <Link text="{parts: [{ path: 'test>key'}, 
                               { path: 'test>value' }], 
                                 formatter : 'dostuff'}"/>
        </VBox>
      </HBox>
    </VBox>
  </l:content>
</l:Grid>
```

And my JSON data is as follows:

```
  {
  "results": [{
          "text": "object1",
          "icon": "icon1",
          "data": [{
              "value1": "foo",
              "value2": "bar"
          }, {
              "value1": "john",
              "value2": "smith"
          }]
      },

      {
          "text": "object2",
          "icon": "icon2",
          "data": [{
              "value1": "adam",
              "value2": "bobson"
          }, {
              "value1": "john",
              "value2": "smith"
          }, {
              "value1": "whatever",
              "value2": "work please"
          }]
      }
  ]
```

}

I want to be able to filter on test>/results/[n]/data/[n]/[value1 + value2] and have the gird filtered at that level.  Whatever I try, it only filters on the Grid content because I can't seem to get the binding for the  in VBox "test".

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to filter the content dynamically from JS? Or statically from the XML directly? I assume that you want to do it from JS.

Your VBox with id test is inside a Grid whose content aggregation you have binded. This means that the whole VBox inside the grid (including the test VBox) is treated as a template for the content aggregation of the grid (i.e. with our JSON, you will end up having two copies of the VBox).

Using this.byId("test") will clearly not work, as it will return a control which is part of the Grid's content aggregation template. So be able to filter the inner VBoxes (because there will be several of them depending on the contents of the model), you have to iterate through the contents of the grid and apply the filtering to each of the target VBoxes. Something along the lines of:

```js
this.byId("grid").getContent().forEach(function(oVbox) {
    // need to get the HBox and the second VBox from it.
    oVbox.getItems()[0].getItems()[1].getBinding("items").filter(...);
});
```

Also, both the Grid and the VBox have the same IDs, so your code will fail because of that as well. Generally, you don't need to define an ID for an aggregation template or a child.

Comment: The ids/data etc is all made up for the sake of this example.

I have made the changes you suggested and it works perfectly!  Now, I want to be able to "hide" the Grid element if all of it's "VBox" items have been filtered.  Any idea on this?

Comment: It depends if you really use a JSON model or not :) if you use a JSON model, then the items aggregation will be immediately updated once you apply the filter --> you can just check the length of the items aggregation immediately after applying the filter (something like `oVboxOuter.setVisible(oVboxInner.getItems().length > 0)`). If you are using an OData model, you will have to listen to the data received event of the binding (because filtering will actually trigger a request; so you will only know if you have at least one item when the data arrives).

Comment: The data arrives from SAP but is then consolidated into the JSON you see above. The data is received once and never again in the life cycle of the App.

Sorry, I should have been clearer earlier... What I meant was I want to be able to FILTER the grid if there are no items (which will 'hide' it).

Comment: To be able to filter it, you need to have "something" in the JSON model to filter against (i.e. a property of the aggregation what you want to filter). My proposal would be: when you are looping on each `content` element of the grid, you can get the length of the `items` aggregation of the inner VBox (as above) and store it in the corresponding result entry in the model in a new property; (you can get the path from the binding context of each element). You can then use this property to filter the Grid's aggregation (you should re-apply this filter each time, after the loop over the contents).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand.  If I filter the Grid then there will be no items in there to filter the items, also the /itemsLength property will not be reset.  I'm doing this `grid.getBinding("content").filter(new Filter("itemsLength", FilterOperator.GT, 0));` after the loop has ended, and this is in the loop: `itemsBinding.filter(new Filter("filterVal", FilterOperator.Contains, text));` and `that._view.getModel("grid").setProperty(path + "/itemsLength", items.getItems().length);`

Comment: ... Also, this is all done on the livechange event of a searchField

Comment: Hmm, I guess that hiding one of the big VBoxes will prevent it from reappearing later (if you e.g. clear the search field). So you would have to first remove the "big" filtering before applying the loop. I played a little around with this is this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6rx86x33/3/

Comment: So I found the issue.  I'm using version 1.28 which doesn't seem to support this level of nested filtering.  It only ever filters on the grid <content>.  I did a test and used https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js which made it work fine.  I will have to wait until my company upgrades :-(