# Binding search on NavigationList

Tags: binding, sapui5

My search method is working only on the first node of my jsonmodel, do i need to make another filter ?

///View

```
    <tnt:NavigationList id="navlist"  items="{path:'cars>/Desc'}" >
        <tnt:NavigationListItem  id="navlistitem" text="{cars>TITLE}"  expanded="true" items="{path:'cars>ITEMS',templateShareable:true}"
                                key="{cars>number}">

                <tnt:NavigationListItem id="navListItemSecond"  text="{cars>TITLE}" key="{cars>number}">

                </tnt:NavigationListItem>
         </tnt:NavigationListItem>
    </tnt:NavigationList>
```

//Controller (The search method)

```
            onLiveSearch:function(evt) {
        var filterString = evt.getParameter('newValue');
        var filters = [];
            var tree = this.getView().byId('navlist');
        var binding = tree.getBinding('items');
        if ( filterString && filterString.length > 0 ) {
            var filter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter( 'TITLE', sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
                filterString );
            filters.push( filter1 );            
        }
        binding.filter(filters);            
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat similar to [Filtering on Nested Aggregation Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507390/filtering-on-nested-aggregation-binding). Basically you have a two-level collection and (I guess) you want to be able to filter both levels (the items of the nav list and the child items of those items) with only one search.

What you have to do is actually filter both the top-level aggregations (the `items` aggregation of the NavigationList) and all the lower level aggregations (each of the `items` aggregations of the NavigationList's NavigationListItems).

Keep in mind that filtering on the `navlistitem`'s items aggregation will **not** work, because this control is actually a template for the aggregation binding (it is cloned at runtime to obtain the items which are displayed). You will have to iterate through all the clones (= the items of the NavigationList) and apply the filter for each of them in order to achieve what you want.